# Can a company return an aircraft in leasing?

Tags: airline-operations, airbus-a380, airlines

regarding A380 I see that Singapore Airline and AirFrance return 2 and 5 respectively to their lessors, so I would like to know, how the give back operation works? Are there any penalty to pay?

I was wondering if Emirates too can give back its A380.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about the legal relationship between Emirates and their leasing company, which to the best of my knowledge is private.

Comment: I'm interested to know about how it usually works. Most airliners are leased and I believe that for a given airline size, deals must be pretty similar. Maybe someone with experience in this field have some interesting info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a penalty to pay if you break the lease contract by returning it before the completion date. Same as a car.  It may be that they simply continue the lease payments to the end of the contract, or the contract may have some kind not-quite-so-bad penalty that was negotiated to sweeten the deal for the airline to get the deal in the first place.

The airline will do a business case and balance the penalty costs of breaking the lease early against the losses of continuing to run their unwanted behemoth to the end of the lease contract and proceed based on the cheaper option.  Even if they have to keep making lease payments to the end of the contract, it still may be worthwhile to return the aircraft and escape from maintenance and insurance costs, if the aircraft was killing them financially, which is what this sort of thing suggests.

Comment: Useless knowledge: the airborne counterpart of a behemoth is a [Ziz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziz).